# Python: How to calculate time duration between current time and a specific time?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I wanted to calculate the time duration between current time and specific time, but it keeps showing **unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'**, what does it mean and why I can't minus the time ?

```
current_time = dt.datetime.now().time()

FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
t1 = '10:33:26'
t1_obj = dt.datetime.strptime(t1, FMT).time()

tduration = current_time - t1_obj
print(tduration)
```

Comment: I have tried to look for it, but what I want is substract only the time, not date

Comment: I used time() to get the time for now(), but I can't subtract it with other time

Comment: TLDR: you can't subtract 2 times, you can only subtract 2 datetimes or subtract 2 timedeltas.

Comment: alright thanks for letting me know that

Comment: do you want delta in hh:mm:yy format?

Comment: yes, but the problem with me is that I wanted to subtract only times, which cannot be done